# How to stop Firefox from updating?

Tags: firefox, updates, firefox-extensions

Anyway here is my problem. I'm currently on beta channel (Firefox 6) which was recently upgraded and broke some extensions. Now I gather those extensions will be upgraded in the future and they'll restore to working order. Is there a way for me to disable further beta updates and keep my Firefox on a stable channel **without** losing my settings and extensions? Is there a way to *backup* Firefox 6 or *disable updating to a beta version* (but keep the updating to a stable versions)?

Comment: All of the answers such as this web page are outdated. Firefox 3.6.25 no longer responds to unticking of the update box. It continues to ask if you want to update despite the fact that important add-ons such SEO Quake will not operate in the latest version of Firfox.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Type `about:config` in the awesome bar and search for the key `app.update.channel`.  Change the value to `release` to get the stable releases only.

[Mozilla KB Article](http://kb.mozillazine.org/App.update.channel)

Answer (score 4):

Uncheck whatever is unnecessary:

[image: Firefox Advanced Options Tab Screenshot]

Comment: Already did. Unfortunately that didn't stop Firefox to update on one occasion (there was a bar notifying me of Firefox being uploaded once I started the program).